# How to detect voltage peaks above a set threshold?

Tags: voltage, analog, spike, voltage-detector

I have a power source that will generate voltage peaks for a very short amount of time (around 20 - 100 Microseconds long). I am trying to develop an electrical circuit that will capture the peak voltage that is measured for slightly longer than this because the measuring equipment I am using does not have a high time resolution.

I was thinking of using some sort of capacitor and diode setup up as in the picture in order to capture the charge transferred for slightly longer than 20 microseconds, but I would like the voltage to drop back down to close to 0 within 50 milliseconds after the peak is measured.

[image: Simple Voltage Peak Detector Circuit]

I found this picture from this website:
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-3/peak-detector/

Could anyone assist me?

Comment: What is the regular voltage of the power source and what is the voltage range of the peaks to be detected?

Comment: Most of the time the voltage is 0. I need to detect when this goes above 0 to maybe around 2V to 10V for 20 microseconds @Jens

Comment: How do you know when to start the measurement? Can you provide a kind of "Clear" signal to discharge the capacitor or do you prefer a discharge ramp with fixed time?